How to create an animated 2D histogram chart in python
I have the code to create my 2D histogram as below. It works for creating a statics chart but I need to create an animated heatmap which change with 'minute_play' column. How can I do that? The picture of the data sample and the output are attached. Below is the code I used to create the 2D histogram (heatmap)


multicolor = ["#ffffff","#e2eeff", "#c3d8f9","#80bdff", "#42b0f5",
              "#a0e242", "#d1cb1c", "#a06a20", "#872a10", "#630d02", "#000000"]
bins = 100

densities,_,_ = np.histogram2d(heatmap_df.params_pos_x, heatmap_df.params_pos_y, bins=bins)
percentiles = [0,1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,99,100]

bounds = []
for i in percentiles:
 bounds.append(np.percentile(np.unique(densities),i))

cmaplist = multicolor
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
           'Custom cmap',
            cmaplist,
            len(percentiles))
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
plt.hist2d(heatmap_df.params_pos_x,
           heatmap_df.params_pos_y,
      bins = bins,
      norm = norm,
       cmap = cmap)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks = bounds)
plt.show()

I have try to follow this but did not really understand what to do next to migrate my code to this guide
https://plotly.com/python/v3/heatmap-animation/

Can you add the definition of heatmap_df to your code?

matplot has matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation - every few milliseconds it runs your function in which you replace previous data with new data, and this makes animation.

example: Animations using Matplotlib — Matplotlib 3.9.0 documentation

Already answered, do you still wish to animate in Plotly?

Here is an example of how to achieve this together with sample data. In my case, I did it in jupyter notebook:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from IPython.display import HTML

np.random.seed(0)
num_entries = 1000
num_minutes = 10

minute_play = np.random.choice(range(num_minutes), size=num_entries)
params_pos_x = np.random.uniform(0, 100, num_entries)
params_pos_y = np.random.uniform(0, 100, num_entries)

heatmap_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'minute_play': minute_play,
    'params_pos_x': params_pos_x,
    'params_pos_y': params_pos_y
})

bins = 50
multicolor = ["#ffffff", "#e2eeff", "#c3d8f9", "#80bdff", "#42b0f5",
              "#a0e242", "#d1cb1c", "#a06a20", "#872a10", "#630d02", "#000000"]
percentiles = [0, 1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 99, 100]

densities, _, _ = np.histogram2d(heatmap_df['params_pos_x'], heatmap_df['params_pos_y'], bins=bins)
bounds = [np.percentile(np.unique(densities), i) for i in percentiles]

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom cmap', multicolor, len(percentiles))
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cbar = fig.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, ticks=bounds)
cbar.set_label('Density')

def update(frame):
    ax.clear()  # Clear the previous plot
    minute_data = heatmap_df[heatmap_df['minute_play'] == frame]
    hist = ax.hist2d(minute_data['params_pos_x'], minute_data['params_pos_y'], bins=bins, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    ax.set_title(f'Minute: {frame}')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(heatmap_df['minute_play'].min(), heatmap_df['minute_play'].max() + 1),
                              repeat=False)

HTML(ani.to_jshtml())

which gives

To save it:
ani.save('animated_heatmap.mp4', writer='ffmpeg')


or
ani.save('animated_heatmap.gif', writer='imagemagick')


hey this is exactly what I need, only a few questions: Do you realize that the Density columns in the chart did not change along with the animation? In my case, it effect the output heatmap, and make it looks blurry as the minute play increases

I would need you data to check that out. Until then, 编码愉快！

Serge, I hope you don't mind that I added this great demo to my animated plots demo notebook that you can easily launch and run with no installs needed using any launch badge here. Because this plotcreates an javascript based controller widget it remains runnable in nbviewer rendered views of the notebook, specifically here for this notebook. (GitHub won't render the controller presently & won't even attempt to display this large notebook.)

It is second from the bottom there.

No problem! Glad you found use for it. If this is what you wanted, don't forget to accept the answer (it'll make it disappear from the list of unanswered questions) and/or upvote.

Sure @SergedeGossondeVarennes. Here is the sample data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xldhT1_lYMQm3RHNJxAG6NSFByoEKMPF/view?usp=sharing
